# Circular Notched Rectangle

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I'm new to flutter.
I'm trying to make this embedded button. But, couldn't find a widget to shape the container like this.

[image]

( I was only able to find the feature for the navigation bar.)

Comment: Do you have a mock where we can see what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers). You can also check [Round_curve](https://gist.github.com/salimmurshed/882b772ed99e54d60b83e0fb7cd19b3b).

[image: Round_curve]